How to update data in PowerPoint table using office.js
How to update data in PowerPoint table using office.js.
First loading slides in powerpoint then loading shapes.
But not able to load tables with rows and columns data.
I am getting slides and shapes
But not table with rows and columns.
Please help me on the same.
async function getSlideCollection() {
 PowerPoint.run(async function (context) {
context.presentation.load("slides");
await context.sync();
const slide = context.presentation.slides.getItemAt(0);
slide.load("id"); // Load any property from the PPT object model
slide.load("shapes");
await context.sync();
console.log(slide.id);
const shape = slide.shapes.getItemAt(1);            
shape.load("tables");            
await context.sync();            
});


The shape object does not have a "tables" property.  You should be able to get the Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text property, but when Shape is a table, a reference to it's TextFrame property throws an exception. I'll report this as a bug.
